# Dynamic parameters passed to page callback

Tags: 7, routes, ajax

I have the following hook_menu:

```
  $items['products/autocomplete.json/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'json_list_products',
    'access arguments' => array('access products')
  );
```

Here is the function:

```
function json_list_products($keywords) {

  $items = array();
  foreach(_sql_select_products($keywords) as $product) {
    $items[$product['Product_ID']] = $product['Product_Name'];
  }    

  drupal_json_output($items);
}
```

$keywords is not populated with the value of the % as i suspected - how do I populate this value?

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$items['products/autocomplete.json/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'json_list_products',
    'access arguments' => array('access products'),
    'page arguments' => array(2),
  );
```

view the documentation at [this link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)

Comment: I have added the 'page arguments' as you have indicated...added an echo $keywords and exited from the json_xxx function and invoked the URI directly like so:

http://domain.ca/products/autocomplete.json/cook

Nothing happens...any ideas??? The documentation is very confusing and no newbie friendly :)

EDIT | I refreshed the cache too

Comment: instead of sing echo...try installing the devel module and using dpm($keywords).

Comment: Figured it out stepping through drupal code...turns out I had 'page argument' not 'page arguments' UGH!!! Thanks again everyone :)

Comment: Sure thing, sorry boss :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this to start:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['products/autocomplete.json/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'json_list_products',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function json_list_products($keywords) {
  drupal_json_output($keywords);
}
```

Note the following:

- Set **page arguments** to position in your path where you expect the arguments in your callback to be. In your case, it's 2;
- I've set **access arguments** to be *access content* which is likely to be enabled for anyone. If this works, then check if you have a *access products* permission when testing;
- Remember to clear your cache after modifications. If you use drush, you can use `drush cc menu` from the command line;
- Use `MENU_CALLBACK` because otherwise Drupal will add a menu item to the Navigation menu, since the default is `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM`.

I've tested this and http://example.org/products/autocomplete.json/cook returns:

```
"cook"
```